# Text cut off when seeding CSV file into database with Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, csv, seeding

When trying to seed my database this happens:

```
Seeding: UsersTableSeeder
array (
  'name' => 'Tester One',
  'email' => 'testerone@gmail.com',
  'password' => 'Testing123',
Tester Two',esterone.png
)
```

The last value of the array shows the name of the next tester and the first character of the image of the first tester is cut off for some reason. The next testers don't even get seeded. When I look into the database, the last column (named 'avatar') shows the whole image file (so testerone.png instead of esterone.png) and also the name of Tester Two.

This is my `UsersTableSeeder.php`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use League\Csv\Reader;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

public function run()
{
    $path = resource_path() .'/postSeed/userseed.csv';
    $reader = Reader::createFromPath($path, 'r');

    $records = $reader->getRecords(['name', 'email', 'password', 'avatar']);
    foreach ($records as $offset => $record) {
        var_export($record);

        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => $record['name'],
            'email' => $record['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($record['password']),
            'created_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            'avatar' => $record['avatar'],
        ]);
    }
}
}
```

This is what my CSV file looks like:

```
Tester One,testerone@gmail.com,Testing123,testerone.png
Tester Two,testertwo@gmail.com,Testing123,testertwo.jpg
Tester Three,testerthree@gmail.com,Testing123,testerthree.jpg
Tester Four,testerfour@live.be,Testing123,testerfour.jpg
Testert Five,testerfive@hotmail.com,Testing123,testerfive.jpg
Tester Six,testersix@stubru.be,Testing123,testersix.jpg
```

If anyone could help me with this that would be great!

Comment: This looks like a problem with your CSV. Can you post the lines for Tester One and Tester Two please?

Comment: Hi @flip, updated with the csv file!

Comment: Sorry, can you open it in a text editor (notepad or gedit) and see the raw format?

Comment: I added the raw format!

Comment: @flip the problem was indeed my CSV files, but not because of the structure weirdly. I just put em in an online CSV viewer and redownloaded them from there and now my problem seems to be fixed!

Comment: Glad you fixed it. I'm guessing it was some hidden character (like a newline) that was making the Reader think the line ended prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

After some looking online, I tried to see if my CSV files were the problem. I put them on [CSV Editor and Viewer](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-viewer-editor.htm) and redownloaded them from there and it suddenly seemed to work. Weird.